# Execute String Formulas from Array

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns which have to be filled with formulas (with 5k to 10k values). Those are simple formulas and they work.
But writing directly into the cells slows the program down too much, so I'm writing the formulas into an array and then pasting the array into the workbook. This works fine too, it just doesn't evaluate the strings. I tried using `EVALUATE`  without success.
If I select any of the copied cells, press F2 and Enter, they work perfectly.

Code sample:

```
ReDim Schreibblock(FirstRow To LastRowPos, 0 To 1)

For j = FirstRow To LastRowPos
    Schreibblock(j, 0) = "=" & SteigungPos.Address & "*$B$" & j & "+" & NullwertPosTren.Address & ""
    Schreibblock(j, 1) = "=ABS($A$" & j & "-$C$" & j & ")"
Next j

Range("C" & FirstRow & ":D" & LastRowPos).Formula = [Schreibblock]
```

and here a "light version" for easier reading:

```
ReDim array(14 To 5000, 0 To 1)

For j = 14 To 5000
    Array(j, 0) = "=$B$10*$B$14+$B$9"  <- This is what I see, but w/o ""
    Array(j, 1) = "=ABS($A$14-$C$14)"  <- This is what I see, but w/o ""
Next j

Range("C14:D5000").Formula = [Array]
```

There are no errors and it's lightening fast compared to wirting every loop into a cell. I would appreciate any help.

Carlos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use R1C1 notation and skip the array and loop:

```
Range("C" & FirstRow & ":C" & LastRowPos).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & SteigungPos.Address(0,0,xlR1C1) & "*RC2 +" & NullwertPosTren.Address(0,0,xlR1C1) & ""
Range("D" & FirstRow & ":D" & LastRowPos).FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(RC1 - RC3)"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped! I don't speak R1C1 notation yet and the referenced cells have moved but I'll try to figure it out.
This solution worked fine:
`Range("C" & FirstRow & ":C" & LastRowPos).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & SteigungPos.Address(SteigungPos.Row, SteigungPos.Column, xlR1C1) & "*RC2+" & NullwertPosTren.Address(NullwertPosTren.Row, NullwertPosTren.Column, xlR1C1) & ""`
`Range("D" & FirstRow & ":D" & LastRowPos).FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(RC1 - RC3)"`